# Table colspan and rowspan issues?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a simple table, that was working fine but today I checked it out and its all messed up. None of the tables I have in my code with `colspan` or `rowspan` show correctly.

```html
<table width="1150" border="0" cellpadding="5" id="bop">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">BOP DRILLS</th>
    <th>DRILLING</th>
    <th>RAMS CLOSE</th>
    <th>WELL SECURE</th>
    <th rowspan="2">FINAL ACC.</th>
    <th>Sec</th>
    <th>Psi</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Recharge</th>
    <th>Sec</th>
    <th>Psi</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="bopdrilling" id="boptext" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ramsclose" id="boptext" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="wellsecure" id="boptext" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="finalsec" id="boptext" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="finalpsi" id="boptext" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="rechargesec" id="boptext" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="rechargepsi" id="boptext" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: table that I get from the above code]

[image: it has to be like:]

Comment: How would "correct" look like?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 I've added an image that shows the correct way underneath

Comment: Maybe a CSS issue? Copy&Paste works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sqw01y0/) (Chrome 45)

Comment: Looks good for me. Are you using bootstrap or something?

Comment: For which browser, which version?

Comment: I edited the question to convert the code from a code block to a snippet so we can see a live example. It rendered as expected for me.

Comment: Why do you even need the rowspan="2" anyway? The image in grey background doesn't need rowspan.